# Outcome of cashiers check not being cashed before expiry date

Tags: united-states, check

What happens to a cashiers check which is not cashed before the expiry date?

Let's say a cashiers check which I took out of my account and gave someone which says "void after 90 days" hasn't been cashed after 90 days, does the amount automatically go back to my account or do I have to do something about it?

Comment: Do you still want to pay that someone?  Has the check been lost, stolen, or destroyed?

Comment: @mbhunter No, let's say the person returns the cashiers check to me. Do I have to take it to the bank for the amount to return back to my account or it would happen automatically once it expires?

Comment: These questions are often best resolved by contacting the bank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an individual its not automatic. One needs to ask the Bank, return the check.

For Corporate Customer depending on how big the relationship is, many a times this is given as a service and there is an automatic return

Answer (score 3):

Banks may still honor the check, depending on state law. Your obligation to pay has not been fulfilled.

To get your money back, you need to wait a specified period of time and file a document reporting the check lost. There is probably a fee for this service.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the expired check in hand and take it back to the bank that issued it to you, I'd think they could do something for you.  (I'd hope they would, anyway.)

But automatically?  I don't think so.